# App resolution support

Tags: android, android-manifest

I have created an app that works fine on Galaxy S3 720 x 1280 but not yet compatible to Nexus 4 768 x 1280, and it looks distorted on Nexus 4. How can I restrict in the manifest to specific resolution sizes?

Comment: you cant make distinction between 720x1280 and 768x1280 via manifest

Comment: use the units for text in SP and for all other in dp. you might have used the px units?

Comment: I have used SP and dp and created dimens files. But the thing is I have backgrounds (hdpi, xhdpi) that looks good on devices like S1 S2 S3, but on Nexus 4 with software buttons the background is starched horizontally and squeezed vertically, so other thing not sit at their places correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for.
[link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/supports-screens-element.html)